upgrade flutter 3.22.0 failed to run
when I upgraded to 3.22.0 in flutter, it failed to run. I already upgrade gradle and java17. I have no idea on the error message, which gradle version supposed to used in flutter 3.22.0? Now it is look like some of the plugin error? what I have tried is flutter clean && flutter pub cache clean & flutter pub get , not work
2024-08-07T17:19:56.508+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pdfx-2.4.0/lib/src/viewer/pdf_page_image_provider.dart:24:55: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]   ImageStreamCompleter load(PdfPageImageProvider key, DecoderCallback decode) =>
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pdfx-2.4.0/lib/src/viewer/pdf_page_image_provider.dart:40:7: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]       DecoderCallback decode) async {
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pdfx-2.4.0/lib/src/viewer/pdf_page_image_provider.dart:24:55: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]   ImageStreamCompleter load(PdfPageImageProvider key, DecoderCallback decode) =>
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pdfx-2.4.0/lib/src/viewer/pdf_page_image_provider.dart:40:7: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]       DecoderCallback decode) async {
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/gif-2.2.0/lib/gif.dart:348:51: Error: The method 'instantiateImageCodec' isn't defined for the class 'PaintingBinding'.
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]  - 'PaintingBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/3.16.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/binding.dart').
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'instantiateImageCodec'.
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]     Codec codec = await PaintingBinding.instance!.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/gradient_widgets-0.6.0/lib/src/gradient_widget.dart:104:73: Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]  - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/3.16.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
2024-08-07T17:19:56.511+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'button'.
2024-08-07T17:19:56.512+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]     final TextStyle textStyleCopy = widget.textStyle ?? theme.textTheme.button!.copyWith(color: Colors.white);
2024-08-07T17:19:56.512+0800 [ERROR] [system.err]                                                                         ^^^^^^
2024-08-07T17:19:56.784+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception
2024-08-07T17:19:56.820+0800 [ERROR] [system.err] 
2024-08-07T17:19:56.911+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED

setting.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader"
    id "com.android.application" version '8.5.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.10" apply false
}

include ':app'

gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

build.gradle( module)
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }


    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
        }

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false

        }
    }
 
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}


dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.arr'], dir: 'libs')

    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])

    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'

    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")

    implementation 'com.github.getActivity:MultiLanguages:8.0'
    implementation "com.github.kongzue.DialogX:DialogX:0.0.46"

}

build.gradle(project)
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



do flutter clean then flutter pub upgrade  flutter pub outdated

Depending on which version you upgraded from, since version 3.16, you need to follow https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply to update to 3.22

i am from 2.10.5 upgrade to 3.22.3

Most probably it looks like a cache issue.
You can replace the variable $kotlin_version with the actual version "1.9.23" and check if it builds
If it does build, then you can either keep it, like that, or maybe remove the caches using
flutter clean

and try rebuilding
